# Find and replace string in main string

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to find a string in a main string and remove it.

Example:

```
@Main_text = 'some text some text... // remove text remove text \\ some text some text'
```

What I want is to remove the following text:

```
// remove string remove string \\ of the main text
```

What I tried

```
declare @main_text varchar(255) = 'some text some text... // remove text remove text \\ some text some text'

SELECT STUFF(@main_text, 
         charindex('//', @main_text), 
         charindex('\\', @main_text) , 
   '');
```

This partly works. it removes the searched text but also remove the end of the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third parameter to `STUFF` is the number of characters, from the starting point in the second parameter, to replace.

```
SELECT
    STUFF(@main_text, 
        CHARINDEX('//', @main_text), 
        CHARINDEX('\\', @main_text) - charindex('//', @main_text) + 2, 
        '')
FROM yourTable
WHERE @main_text LIKE '%//%\\%'b
```

### Demo

```
 text // blah \\
      6       14
```

We want to remove `blah` *and* remove the markers.  The difference in marker positions returned from `CHARINDEX` is 8, but we want to remove 10 characters, hence the +2 in the `STUFF` call.

We may use a `WHERE` clause to restrict the query from only targeting records having the replacement markers.  You could put the above query into a CTE, and then update it.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I botched it...for some reason I thought `CHARINDEX` counted the end position of the string, rather than the beginning.

Comment: And if my main text does not contains the slash and backslash?

Comment: @I_G Wait...I get it...just add a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: In my case I will use a "CASE". Thanks.